# How do I implement a NamingContainer? All children get the same client ID

Tags: jsf, tree, custom-component, jsf-1.2, naming-containers

I try to write my own tree component. A tree node renders as a div containing child components of the tree component, for example:

```
<my:tree id="extendedTree"
         value="#{controller.rootNode}"
         var="node">
    <h:outputText id="xxx" value="#{node.name}" />
    <h:commandLink value="Test" actionListener="#{controller.nodeSelectionActionListener}" />
</my:tree>
```

So far, so good - everything works as expected, but the `h:outputText` gets the same id repeatedly.
So I had my component implement `javax.faces.NamingController`, overwriting `getContainerClientId()`:

```
@Override
public String getContainerClientId(FacesContext context) {
    String clientId = super.getClientId(context);
    String containerClientId = clientId + ":" + index;
    return containerClientId;
}
```

`index` is set and updated during iteration over the nodes. But `getContainerClientId()` is called only once for every children (not for every iteration and every children, as I would expect). That causes every child id to be prefixed with the same container id:

```
form:treeid:0:xxx
```

Same thing for overwriting `getClientId()`.

What did I miss?

Comment: My humble plea goes to Curaçao, is there someone knowing the answer? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the bottom of chapter 3.1.6 of [JSF 1.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-1.2-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> ## 3.1.6 Client Identifiers
>
> ...
>
> The value returned from this method must be the same throughout
>   the lifetime of the component instance unless `setId()` is called, in which case it will be
>   recalculated by the next call to `getClientId()`.

In other words, the outcome of [`getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) is by default cached by the JSF component as implemented in [`UIComponentBase#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) (see also the nullcheck at [line 275 as it is in Mojarra 1.2_15](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/1.2_15/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java#UIComponentBase.getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29)) and this cache is resetted when the `UIComponentBase#setId()` is called (see also [line 358 as it is in Mojarra 1.2_15](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/1.2_15/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java#UIComponentBase.setId%28java.lang.String%29)). As long as you don't reset the cached client ID, it will return the same value on every `getClientId()` call.

So, while rendering the children in `encodeChildren()` implementation of your component or the renderer which shall most probably look like this,

```
for (UIComponent child : getChildren()) {
    child.encodeAll(context);
}
```

you should for every child be calling [`UIComponent#setId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29) with the outcome of [`UIComponent#getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29) to reset the internally cached client ID before encoding the child:

```
for (UIComponent child : getChildren()) {
    child.setId(child.getId());
    child.encodeAll(context);
}
```

The `UIData` class behind the `<h:dataTable>` implementation does that by the way also (see [line 1382 as it is in Mojarra 1.2_15](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/1.2_15/javax/faces/component/UIData.java#UIData.restoreDescendantState%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent%2Cjavax.faces.context.FacesContext%29)). Note that this is not JSF 1.x specific, the same applies on JSF 2.x as well (and also on `UIRepeat` class behind Facelets `<ui:repeat>`).

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that if your component's children have children, then it may also be necessary to refresh their cached ids, too.  With this mark-up, slightly adapted from the original:

```
<my:tree id="extendedTree"
         value="#{controller.rootNode}"
         var="node">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="nodeBlock">
    <h:outputText id="xxx" value="#{node.name}" />
    <h:commandLink value="Test" actionListener="#{controller.nodeSelectionActionListener}" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</my:tree>
```

The id for the `<panelGroup>` comes out OK after applying BalusC's fix above but all the sub-components come out with 0 in the iterator.

To fix that, iterate through all the levels of children too and refresh their cached ids.  So:
`child.setId(child.getId());` becomes `uncacheId(child);` where the `uncacheId` function is defined:

```
private void uncacheId(UIComponent el) {
    el.setId(el.getId());
    el.getChildren().forEach(this::uncacheId);
}
```

That may be obvious but it took me a while to figure out, so ...

Answer (score -2):

h:outputText id gives you same as you didn't make it dynamic. You can create it like:

```
 <h:outputText id="xxx_#{node.id}" value="#{node.name}" />
```

Assume node has an 'id' attribute which is an unique.

Comment: My component should replicate the behaviour of other NamingContainers (e.g. UIData): There is no need to make the id dynamic as they are prefixed automatically with a row-ID (index in my case).

Comment: This is absolutely not going to work. The ID attribute is evaluated during view build time while the `<my:tree>` is clearly an UI component and not a taghandler. Please don't post answers without actually having recreated and solved the problem in your local sandbox environment.